# How to plot a 3-column matrix as a color map in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, plot, color-mapping

I have a matrix containing the temperature value for a set of GPS coordinates. So my matrix looks like this :

```
Longitude  Latitude  Value
---------  --------  -----
12.345678  23.456789   25 
12.345679  23.456790   26
%should be :
%  x           y        z
```

etc.

I want to convert this matrix into a human-viewable plot like a color plot (2D or 3D), how can I do this?

3D can be something like this : 
[image]

or just the 2-D version of this (looking from top z-axis).

### What Have I Tried

I know MATLAB has `surf` and `mesh` functions but I cannot figure out how to use them.

If I call

```
surf(matrix(:,1) , matrix(:,2) , matrix(:,3));
```

I get the error :

```
Error using surf (line 75)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

**P.S :** It would also be great if there is a function that "fills" the gaps by interpolation (smoothing, whatever :) ). Since I have discrete data, it would be more beautiful to represent it as a continous function.

**P.S 2 :** I also want to use [plot_google_map](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27627-plotgooglemap) in the z=0 plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A surprisingly hard-to-find answer. But I'm lucky that somebody else has asked almost the same question [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243056).

I'm posting the answer that worked for me :

```
x = matrix(:,1);
y = matrix(:,2);
z = matrix(:,3);
  xi=linspace(min(x),max(x),30)
  yi=linspace(min(y),max(y),30)
  [XI YI]=meshgrid(xi,yi);
  ZI = griddata(x,y,z,XI,YI);
  contourf(XI,YI,ZI)
```

which prints a nice color map.

Comment: Is your data defined on a rectangular grid? If so, there's a much simpler way.

Comment: Not exactly a grid. It's just a mobile phone's sensor output while I was walking on a certain road. But I am planning to convert it to a grid. So I would like to hear your solution.

Comment: Well, if it's not on a grid, I think you've got a decent solution already. You can read more here as well (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-scattered-data.html). I'll post up another answer that avoids using the griddata function too.

Comment: I have data in rectangular format. Also, one field is string and two fields are integers. I want to plot a 3d graph with these three columns.

Answer (score 1):

One option that avoids unnecessarily gridding your data would be to compute the Delaunay triangulation of the scattered data points and then using a command like `trisurf` to plot the data. Here's an example:

```
N=50;
x = 2*pi*rand(N,1);
y = 2*pi*rand(N,1);
z = sin(x).*sin(y);

matrix = [x y z];

tri = delaunay(matrix(:,1),matrix(:,2));
trisurf(tri,matrix(:,1),matrix(:,2),matrix(:,3))
shading interp
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your matrix is `nx3`. Then you can create the grid as follows:

```
xMin=min(myMat(:,1));
xMax=max(myMat(:,1));
yMin=min(myMat(:,2));
yMax=max(myMat(:,2));

step_x=0.5; %depends on your data

[xGrid,yGrid]=meshgrid(xMin:step_x:xMax,yMin:step_y:yMax);
```

Now, put your data in the third column to the appropriate indices, in the new matrix say, `valMat`.

You can use `surf` now as follows:

```
surf(xGrid,yGrid,valMat);
```

If you want interpolation, you can convolve a Gaussian kernel (maybe 3x3) with `valMat`.