# 1D-Data for engine map plot in MATLAB/ lookup-table in Simulink

Tags: matlab, dictionary, interpolation, lookup, simulink

I have some measured data (1D-Data - hope it is correct to name it in that way), for example a table with three columns. (see below)

[Example measurement data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tueC.png)

For example in the first row at 1000rpm speed and 57% throttle position the engine generates 30Nm of torque. Now I want to use this data for two use cases:

---

1. in a 2D-lookup-table in Simulink.

Speed and throttle position is provided als input and the lookup-table should "interpolate" torque as output.

[Lookup table setup in Simulink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eytZ.png)

I created three vectors with the da from each column in the table and entered them in the lookup-table parameters but there appears some error:

*"Error occurred while retrieving data, check the selected block's parameter setting.
Error reported by block ''spielwiese/2-D Lookup Table'': The number of dimensions in the table data is 1 while the number of dimensions specified in the block is 2. They must match."*

Is it possible to interpolate or extend the data to use it in this lookup table?

---

2. in a plot to create an engine map.

Like this one: [engine map - source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Engine-map-engine-torque-vs-throttle-and-engine-RPM_fig7_261390259](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMqCQ.png)

I tried to create a map with contourf but I got no result. Maybe some of you know how to create such a plot with this data.

Hope you can project my thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, ask only one question per post.

Comment: To understand what you are getting wrong, think about how you would be the torque for an input of 1000 rpm and a throttle position of 100%?

Answer (score 0):

I found several sources which helped me to solve my problem:

[How to plot a 3-column matrix as a color map in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672811/how-to-plot-a-3-column-matrix-as-a-color-map-in-matlab)

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/interpolation.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav

https://de.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ug/import-efficiency-map-motorcad.html?searchHighlight=Import%20Efficiency%20Map%20Data%20from%20Motor-CAD%20Open%20Model&s_tid=srchtitle_Import%20Efficiency%20Map%20Data%20from%20Motor-CAD%20Open%20Model_1 (see source code from plot)

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples.html?category=interpolation&s_tid=CRUX_topnav

https://www.gomatlab.de/matrix-interpolation-t23744.html